# Get File Path From Drop Event

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that allows users to drag and drop files in IE.

The problem I have is that they would like the file deleted after being dragged, but I can't seem to get the file path, just the name.

I have seen many references to `e.dataTransfer.files[0].path`, but it always comes back as `'undefined'` when I try it.

Any ideas why `e.dataTransfer.files[0].path` does not work, or how I can get the file path?

```
 $(document).ready(function (ex) {
        var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
        holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
        holder.ondrop = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
            var path = e.dataTransfer.files[0].path;
            fileArray.push(file);
            //alert(e.target.id);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };
    });
```

Comment: For security reasons browsers do not allow this, i.e. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System

Answer (score 9):

that's not possible for a web app, but if your users would run an app on their machine, you could build an electron app. inside electron you get the `e.dataTransfer.files[0].path` property, which you can then use to delete the file.

https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: Was trying to clean up my solution in an Electron app. Had about 25 lines of code with nested promises using the DataTransferItemList web API to hack a solution together. Using your advice, I was able to replace all that with a single line of code, so much cleaner. Seriously, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The file doesn't have property `path`.

You can experiment with it [here](https://jsbin.com/vuyifovido/edit?html,js,output) and the complete list of file properties can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

To read the file one uses [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) as you did, without using the `path` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything I could find, I am of the opinion that it is not possible.